# Could worn out front shocks cause extensive inner tire wear?

Tags: tires, suspension, shock-absorber

I have a problem where both front tires on my 1989 Toyota truck are wearing out the inner tread at an abnormal rate.  So much so in fact that steel belt broke through on the drivers side tire and I had to replace it.  The passenger side front tire has significant inner tread wear as well.  All tires (rear and front) were installed together new less than 2 years ago, so there is a serious problem.

I try to perform all my own repairs, or at least diagnose the problems myself and buy the parts needed and take to my buddy's garage for the labor to install.  I watched youtube videos on alignment and followed the preliminary diagnostic steps.  The truck does not veer to either direction when steering wheel is released in straight driving. The visual inspection did not show any serious toe, camber, or caster alignment problems, at least not to the extend that would cause such abnormal inner tire wear.  The shocks are shot on both sides however.  I can really feel the potholes. Could the bad shocks be mainly responsible for the abnormally excessive inner front tire wear?

The rear tires are still good with no abnormal wear.  Breaking system is fine.

Comment: You can't really eyeball camber, caster etc...  You really just need to take it into a shop with the proper equipment and have everything checked, but replace the shocks first, since you'll just have to get a second alignment otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

First you should have replaced both front tyres together : braking stabilty water clearance etc

As for a visual check of caster, camber and kpi then if you can see 0.5 or 1 degree of misalignment thats good going and any garage would save on buying expensive equipment.

I suggest you get an expert to do a 4 way alignment to see what the issues are.

Oh, and those shocks should have been replaced long ago....